# Why is ICMP timestamping disabled on OS X?

Tags: macos, icmp, timestamp

It would seem like [ICMP timestamping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172028/awk-hping-print-difference-between-icmp-originate-receive/20186781#20186781) is quite a useful feature for troubleshooting networks with asymmetric paths.

Replies to [icmp(4)](http://mdoc.su/f/icmp.4) timestamp requests are generated by the kernel:

- On OpenBSD, the feature is controlled by sysctl [net.inet.icmp.tstamprepl](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/netinet/icmp_var.h#ICMPCTL_TSTAMPREPL), which is [enabled](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/netinet/ip_icmp.c#icmptstamprepl) by default.
- FreeBSD even has no option to disable only the timestamp feature of ICMP (see `case ICMP_TSTAMP` in [icmp_input()](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/netinet/ip_icmp.c#icmp_input))

On OS X, the respective setting is [net.inet.icmp.timestamp](https://superuser.com/questions/680200/os-x-how-to-make-it-reply-to-icmp-time-stamp-query), which is specifically disabled by default.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

The ICMP timestamp response contains the remote host's date and time. This information could theoretically be used against some systems to exploit weak time-based random number generators in other services

Comment: But most modern systems have clocks set to the same time within a few seconds -- and I think Mac OS X even synchronizes using NTP by default.